# Resource: Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, online-resources

There is a [website](http://cage.ugent.be/geometry/theses.php) providing recent thesis in finite geometry. Is there any website with collection of recent thesis on (finite) group theory.

I want to see the Ph.D. thesis of Raymond T. Shepherd, "p-Groups of Maximal Class", and A. J. Weir, "Sylow-p Subgroups of Symmetric and Classical Groups" .

Comment: [tag:reference-request] should not be used as a standalone tag; see [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info) and [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags). In particular, I have taken the liberty of adding the [tag:group-theory] tag to this post.

Comment: @mixdmath: ok...allright

Comment: [Here is a link to the holding at university of chicago's library](https://libcat.uchicago.edu/ipac20/ipac.jsp?session=13455PW527139.54477&profile=ucpublic&uri=link=3100007~!5346730~!3100001~!3100002&aspect=subtab13&menu=search&ri=1&source=~!horizon&term=p-Groups+of+maximal+class.&index=ALTITLP). Usually university libraries have a system where you can request books from other libraries.

Comment: In fact, I happened to check if Brown's library system knew where a copy was, and they do. There is a copy available from ProQuest Dissertation and Theses Database. This is behind a paywall, but one that many universities have access to.

Comment: (Most) British theses are available from the [British library](http://ethos.bl.uk/Home.do). If they are recent enough they will be in digital format and you can download them for...free (although this "free-ness" may just be because I am at a (UK) university). Also, when I say "recent enough" I mean that every thesis today is digitised. However, I just found one from 2009 which is not. So...you *may* have to pay a "digitisation" fee (although I believe most of the time the awarding institution will pay for it instead) and you *will* have to wait 30 days for them to digitise it.

Comment: (I say "most" because I did a quick search for "groups". Marcus Du Sautoy's thesis was the first result, and you cannot download it! It looks like it might be an Oxford thing - I access any Oxford thesis.)

Comment: Shepherd's thesis is from 1970! I am not sure you can call this recent...Leedham-Green and MacKay have a book on $p$-groups which begins with a classification of $p$-groups of maximal class. Would this book not suit?

Comment: @user1729:  Was 'I access any Oxford thesis' meant to be 'I can't access any Oxford thesis'?  I remember finding Claas Röver's thesis without any trouble.

Comment: @TaraB: Yeah, okay, I have found it too. I dunno - that comment was made a few months ago, and I tried a few people who I knew had graduated on the past few years. Maybe 1999 is long enough ago that Oxford do not mind releasing it? Or maybe my search just wasn't good enough? Or maybe it is a college thing?